# Spring Restful service URL encoding issue with "."

Tags: java, http, spring-mvc, url-encoding, spring-restcontroller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/newLoadtest/{loadtest}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody void addNewLoadTest(@PathVariable("loadtest") String loadtest) {
        System.out.println(loadtest);
}
```

This is the code that I have written and if lets say the loadtest string is "test.version" . The period doesn't work for some reason.  It prints out "test" only

I think the issue here might be encoding the url but i am not sure how to go about it. Please help

Comment: Read http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping-suffix-pattern-match

Answer (score 0):

Its spring's smart way to avoid any suffix in URI. You have two ways to disable it.

add ":.+" after your path variable definition.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/newLoadtest/{loadtest:.+}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

Another way is  to
Use your own "DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" and disable "useDefaultSuffixPattern" to false.

Answer (score 0):

Check below quote from [Spring reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-suffix-pattern-match):

> By default Spring MVC automatically performs ".*" suffix pattern matching so that a controller mapped to /person is also implicitly mapped to /person.*. This allows indicating content types via file extensions, e.g. /person.pdf, /person.xml, etc. A common pitfall however is when the last path segment of the mapping is a URI variable, e.g. /person/{id}. While a request for /person/1.json would correctly result in path variable id=1 and extension ".json", when the id naturally contains a dot, e.g. /person/joe@email.com the result does not match expectations. Clearly here ".com" is not a file extension.

if you do not want to use extension content negotiation you can disable it by this line in below code `configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);` or I think the below solution is better to just use registered Suffix, it is up to your needs

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
    //configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);//this will disable all suffices from negotiation
    configurer.setUseRegisteredSuffixPatternMatch(true);
}
}
```